# Android : what category of intent filter should i use

Tags: android, android-intent

In the second and third activity, in the intent filter what should i use in category.In the second activity i used default but after making third activity i do not know what category should i use.
This is the first android app i am trying to make.Please help me,which categoty should i use in second and third activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- for json call -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/login"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".login.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".login.Menu"
        android:label="@string/second_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool.login.Menu" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.       " />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".login.Attendance"
        android:label="@string/attendance_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool.login.Attendance" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.       " />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: depends on your needs ... if you are starting it like `startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu.class));` then you can just omit `<intent-filter/>` and use `<activity android:name="class" android:label="label" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you get rid of the second and third `<intent-filter>` elements entirely. Only have `<intent-filter>` elements on activities that you expect other apps to link to. You do not need action strings for starting your own activities -- you can use explicit `Intents` (e.g., `new Intent(this, csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool.login.Menu.class)`).

If, for some reason, you are expecting other developers to directly start your `Menu` or `Attendance` activities, then the simplest thing is to put them in the `DEFAULT` category as well. A call to `startActivity()` automatically adds the `DEFAULT` category to the `Intent`, if the `Intent` has not specified another category.

Comment: I am done with my question.But i just want to know...Can we use DEFAULT two times in second and third <intent-filter> element in category.Or we have to use unique 'category' for each <intent-filter>

Comment: @Rob: You are most certainly welcome to use the `DEFAULT` category in several `<intent-filter>` elements.